# How to make a navigation menu item with symmetrical background

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to get the background to each nav link fixed.  I want it to be uniform behind each link, meaning equal on both left and right side.

[Link](http://www.oklahomastepparentadoption.com/truck-web/index.php) to the actual webpage.

See the code below the picture.

Thanks.

[image]

```html
<div class="top-nav">
  <span class="menu"><img src="images/menu.png" alt=""></span>

  <ul class="nav1" style="margin-top: .5em;">
    <li class="hvr-sweep-to-bottom active"><a href="index.php">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="hvr-sweep-to-bottom"><a href="fleet.php">Fleet Management</a>
      <ul class="level_1">
        <li><a href="#">Basic</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Basic Plus</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Ultra</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Ultra Plus</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="hvr-sweep-to-bottom"><a href="services.php">Broker Agency</a>
    </li>
    <li class="hvr-sweep-to-bottom"><a href="maintenance.php">Maintenance</a>
    </li>
    <li class="hvr-sweep-to-bottom"><a href="blog.php">Drivers</a>
    </li>
    <li class="hvr-sweep-to-bottom"><a href="mail.php">Contact</a>
    </li>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
  </ul>
```

And the CSS

```css
.top-nav {
  float: right;
  width: 80%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 27%;
  top: 20%;
}
.top-nav ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.top-nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: .4em;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}
.top-nav ul li.active {
  background: #bb1e10;
}
.top-nav ul li a {
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 18px;
  margin-right: .4em;
  float: left;
  padding: 1em 0em 1em 1.4em;
  text-align: center;
  width: 79%;
}
.top-nav ul li a i {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 1em;
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 11px;
  font-style: italic;
}
.top-nav ul ul {
  display: none;
  left: 0;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}
.top-nav ul ul li {
  float: none;
  width: 200px;
  z-index: 1;
}
.top-nav ul ul li a {
  padding: 5px 5px;
}
.top-nav ul li:hover > ul {
  display: block;
}
/* Sweep To Bottom */

.hvr-sweep-to-bottom {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  -o-transform: translateZ(0);
  -moz-transform: translateZ(0);
  -ms-transform: translateZ(0);
  transform: translateZ(0);
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -o-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -ms-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  -ms-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  -o-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transition-property: color;
  -o-transition-property: color;
  -moz-transition-property: color;
  -ms-transition-property: color;
  transition-property: color;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -o-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -moz-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -ms-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
}
.hvr-sweep-to-bottom:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: #bb1e10;
  -webkit-transform: scaleY(0);
  -o-transform: scaleY(0);
  -moz-transform: scaleY(0);
  -ms-transform: scaleY(0);
  transform: scaleY(0);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 0;
  -o-transform-origin: 50% 0;
  -moz-transform-origin: 50% 0;
  -ms-transform-origin: 50% 0;
  transform-origin: 50% 0;
  -webkit-transition-property: transform;
  -o-transition-property: transform;
  -moz-transition-property: transform;
  -ms-transition-property: transform;
  transition-property: transform;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -o-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -moz-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -ms-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
  -o-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
  -moz-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
  -ms-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
  transition-timing-function: ease-out;
}
.hvr-sweep-to-bottom:hover,
.hvr-sweep-to-bottom:focus,
.hvr-sweep-to-bottom:active {
  color: white;
}
.hvr-sweep-to-bottom:hover:before,
.hvr-sweep-to-bottom:focus:before,
.hvr-sweep-to-bottom:active:before {
  -webkit-transform: scaleY(1);
  transform: scaleY(1);
}
/*---*/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have added some JavaScript as well (for animations and swipe downs). I was able to mimic something, which doesn't have animations, but works as expected. Have a look here in the full screen:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Segoe UI';
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
.nav {
  display: block;
}
.nav > li {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}
.nav > li:hover,
.nav > li.active {
  background-color: #f00;
  color: #fff;
}
.nav a {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
  color: inherit;
}
.nav ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: #f00;
  color: #fff;
}
.nav > li:hover ul {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav">
  <li class="hvr-sweep-to-bottom active">
    <a href="index.php">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li class="hvr-sweep-to-bottom">
    <a href="fleet.php">Fleet Management</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Basic</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Basic Plus</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Ultra</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Ultra Plus</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="hvr-sweep-to-bottom">
    <a href="services.php">Broker Agency</a>
  </li>
  <li class="hvr-sweep-to-bottom">
    <a href="maintenance.php">Maintenance</a>
  </li>
  <li class="hvr-sweep-to-bottom">
    <a href="blog.php">Drivers</a>
  </li>
  <li class="hvr-sweep-to-bottom">
    <a href="mail.php">Contact</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

---

**Update**

To fix your issue, please add this to the bottom of the `style.css`:

```
.nav {
  display: block;
  margin: 25px;
  float: left;
}
.nav > li {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}
.nav > li:hover,
.nav > li.active {
  background-color: #f00;
  color: #fff;
}
.nav a {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #fff;
}
.nav ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: #f00;
  color: #fff;
  z-index: 1;
}
.nav > li:hover ul {
  display: block;
}
```

So this gives an output like this:

[image: preview]

Comment: I wonder if the animation is making it work incorrectly. Think it might be?  Because in a simple form, It always works as intended, but on my website, it doesn't.

Comment: @j_allen_morris I don't think so. It is because of the font, and also it is because of the way, the other CSS rules mess up.

Comment: hmmmm....I have no idea what to do to fix it.  Why can't CSS be simple?????

Comment: @j_allen_morris Because it is so good, it has to be applied correctly. `:(` See the power of CSS. `:D`

Comment: So you're saying it is complicated therefore it is good?  ;)  Sounds good but not sure I agree. lol

Comment: @j_allen_morris It is complicated because it can do wonderful things. `:)` Agree?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129454/discussion-between-j-allen-morris-and-praveen-kumar).

Comment: If anyone is here looking at this in 2019....USE BOOTSTRAP!!!!  Seriously, I avoided it for years, and now that I've gotten used to it, it's amazing.  It's not perfect, but it's way better than doing this stuff by hand.

Comment: @j_allen_morris That's true. Why suddenly?

Comment: I'm not a programmer for my career but I have some new projects and I started looking at things that others use all the time but I haven't and I really like Bootstrap.